# Rounded button animation on hover - border move effect

Tags: css, html, css-animations

I'm wondering, if it's possible to archieve this effect on a rounded button ?

My button looks like in attachment.

[image]

Regards,
Mark.

Comment: Can you explain what is the animation that you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add

```
border-radius: 25px;
```

to the css class buttonContainer It will work  (i'm not sure about the animation tho)

Comment: Animation will be then buggy.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really said what the animation should do, but this CSS creates the look you've shown:

```
 #btnTest { border-radius:25px; 
            font-family:Arial; 
            color:#00f; 
            border: 5px solid #00f;
            padding:5px; 
            width:100px;
           }
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/57cds145/